# Cannot boot 11.10 after 8.04 installation

Tags: 11.10, grub2, bootloader, 8.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 8.04, before that I had 11.10. My intend was to use both of them.

After installation of 8.04, an item for 11.10 didn't appear in grub. What can I do to get it back?

PS: 11.10 using ext4, 8.04 using ext3, so I can't do mount operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Ubuntu 8.04 used grub 1, and ext4 was not supported yet, so it is most probably a grub problem.

The solution is to start with a 11.10 livecd and restore grub 2 using the usual procedures, see for example [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) (I know, you don't installed Windows, but the procedure is the same).